# Special characters like comma(,) and dot(.) are getting ignored while inserting data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert some data in that table that contains comma and dots. Insert is successfully but comma and dot are getting ignored. i am getting the value without special characters while select.

```
INSERT FLEET_CAB_LANDMARK_MASTER (LOCATION_ID, LANDMARK_NAME, AREA, ZONE, IS_ACTIVE, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE_TIME, LANDMARK_TYPE)
values(134,'Mugalsan Road , asz OPP. ICICI ATM','Airoli',40,1,'SYSTEM',getdate(),'G')
```

Comment: Please show us the insert and select queries.

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: mmm, hang on a sec, let me look into my crystal ball to see what your CREATE TABLE statements look like and what your INSERT statements look like...

Comment: Itseems to work fine at my side, can you please share your piece of code ?

Comment: below is the insert script

Comment: INSERT FLEET_CAB_LANDMARK_MASTER (LOCATION_ID, LANDMARK_NAME, AREA, ZONE, IS_ACTIVE, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE_TIME,  LANDMARK_TYPE)
values(134,'Mugalsan Road , asz OPP. ICICI ATM','Airoli',40,1,'SYSTEM',getdate(),'G')

Comment: Can you show the `FLEET_CAB_LANDMARK_MASTER` table create statement?

Comment: *Insert Ron Burgundy 'I don't believe you' GIF here*

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wrap your column name in square brackets to have your identifier delimited:
Say you have sample column that contains special character then you want to 
run something like this:

```
SELECT [Sample] FROM Table1
```

Comment: Yes can you please show us the error message that you are receiving and also if possible a couple of data rows from that table please?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no issues as such, please try the below query and let us know

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
A_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
COMMENTS VARCHAR(50)
)


INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('Test . Best , Fist')

SELECT * FROM #Test
```

Comment: for other table its working fine, only one table it is causing the problem. That's why even i am confused.

Comment: Kinda strange, can you please share the `CREATE` statement used?